# yii multiple ajax submit buttons with CActiveForm

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii, submit-button

well I do have partial form with its ajaxsubmitbutton and it's working alright, but If I tried to partially render another form with another ajaxsubmitbutton, or even add another submitbutton under that form it doesn't work.
here's my ajaxbutton code:

```
 echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
                'Delete', array(
            'submit' => $this->createUrl('logInOfficeEmp/delete', array('id' => $model->id)),
            'type' => 'POST',
                ), array('type' => 'post',), array('id' => 'deletesubmit',));
```

the reason might because the action was supposed to be delete :

```
jQuery('body').undelegate('#deletesubmit','click').delegate('#deletesubmit','click',function(){jQuery.ajax({'type':'POST','url':'/mySystem/index.php?r=logInOfficeEmp/update&id=159', 'cache':false,'data':jQuery(this).parents("form").serialize()});return false;});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be connected to button id (deletesubmit). I think you should use something unique, as example try to replace code:

```
array('id' => 'deletesubmit',)
```

with:

```
array('id' => 'deletesubmit_'.$model->id,)
```